# Rank of covariance matrix

Tags: matrix-rank, covariance, svd

I am having a problem with rank deficiency in a covariance matrix.

I have a data-set of M variables and N observations, M>N.

Calculating the singular value decomposition of the data-sets covariance matrix (MxM) I find that it has rank=N-1 and not M.

Maybe someone here can explain to me why.

Below is a small-scale example:

data:

```
   -0.3430   -1.4018   -0.1397   -0.7793    0.9132
    1.6663   -1.3601   -0.9833   -1.7622    0.9764
   -0.7667   -1.5217    0.4078   -1.9355   -1.5769
    2.6355    1.0547    0.2430    1.5269    0.2041
   -0.0168   -0.1278    0.3975    0.6787   -1.8883
    0.3042   -1.4103   -0.1757   -2.2772    0.7362
    0.6843    0.6029   -0.3175   -1.4286    1.1169
    0.0558   -0.4569   -1.1016   -1.1146    0.7434
```

covariance matrix:

```
    0.7326    0.8063    0.1298   -0.3592   -0.6147    0.8389    0.3320    0.4167
    0.8063    2.3060    0.1711    0.4710   -0.8912    1.6259    1.1083    0.9849
    0.1298    0.1711    0.8714   -0.1736    0.2504    0.5108    0.0355   -0.2082
   -0.3592    0.4710   -0.1736    1.0184    0.4131   -0.2144   -0.0841   -0.0075
   -0.6147   -0.8912    0.2504    0.4131    1.0045   -0.8427   -0.7919   -0.7248
    0.8389    1.6259    0.5108   -0.2144   -0.8427    1.5615    0.9651    0.7206
    0.3320    1.1083    0.0355   -0.0841   -0.7919    0.9651    1.0335    0.6954
    0.4167    0.9849   -0.2082   -0.0075   -0.7248    0.7206    0.6954    0.6295
```

Singular values:

```
5.7404    1.6008    1.3164    0.5000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000
```

Matlab code used:

```
M = 8;
N = 5;
rng(5);
data = randn(M, N);
cov_matrix = cov(data')';
[U,S,V]=svd(cov_matrix);

fprintf('Rank of data: %0.f\n', rank(data));
fprintf('Rank of covariance: %0.f\n', rank(cov_matrix));
fprintf('Rank of singular values: %0.f\n', rank(S));

figure;
plot(diag(S));
```

Comment: Okay, I have included an example by copying the matrices and code used. Does that help?

Comment: [Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/178587/why-is-the-rank-of-covariance-matrix-at-most-n-1) you can find the answer for your question.